# how to implement a user space multi-thread vm e.g. Erlang runtime

Tags: c, linux, erlang

How does the Erlang runtime implement a user-space multi-threaded mechanism on UNIX-like systems?

Is it implemented using something like `getcontext(2)` or `longjump(3)`?

Any related documentation would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlecHenderson_v1.00 why do you think it is badly written answer?

Comment: @om-nom-nom (did you mean badly written *question*?) Because literally the first hit (for me) on Google for 'unix multi thread' is Kevin's link.

Comment: @Kninnug my question is about the user space thread implement. lots of "thread" corresponding to fixed number of thread context in the kernel. I'm considering the switch and scheduler of "thread" in the user space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Erlang process is just a struct with a heap and a stack in it. So switching process is just a matter of using another struct in an queue. I think [this](http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2:392243) paper describes it nicely.